# Bash parameter expansion rules for backslash character

Tags: string, bash, shell, replace

I have a variable, and I want to replace every occurrence of backslash ('\') with double backslash ('\\') using [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). Originally, I used the following construction:

```
$ var='\\a\b'
$ echo "${var//\\/\\\\}"
\\\\a\\b
```

This works fine, but it breaks vim syntax highlighting - apparently, vim cannot handle `\\}` part. So, I decided to store backslash in a variable and use to to avoid syntax highlighting issues:

```
$ bsl='\'
$ echo "${var//$bsl/$bsl$bsl}"
\\a\b
```

To my surprise, it does not work, although it would work fine with any alphanumeric symbol. So, maybe I need to store 2 backslashes in a variable? Let's try it:

```
$ bsl='\\'
$ echo "${var//$bsl/$bsl$bsl}"
\\\\\\\\a\\\\b
```

Now, it went from not working to working twice the time I need. Eventually, I found that the only way to achieve desired result and preserve vim highlighting is the following:

```
$ bsl='\'
$ echo "${var//\\/$bsl$bsl}"
\\\\a\\b
```

While I already found a way to solve my issue, my question is: why parameter expansion works this way with a backslash? To me, such behavior makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Bash manual, with `${parameter/pattern/string}`, "the pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion." Quoting the variable will protect it from pathname expansion and quote/backslash removal.

```
$ echo "${var//$bsl/$bsl$bsl}"
\\a\b
$ echo "${var//"$bsl"/$bsl$bsl}"
\\\\a\\b
```

For what it's worth, if you're on a GNU system you could use `printf %q` to achieve a similar result.

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$var"
\\\\a\\b
```

Comment: However, if I quote replacement part, while removing quotes around whole variable, it also works correctly: `$ echo ${var//"$bsl"/"$bsl$bsl"}` -> `\\\\a\\b`. I still don't get it.

Comment: Quote/backslash removal only applies to characters that weren't the result of an expansion. Quoting isn't needed to protect the backslashes in `$var` from being removed. It *is* useful to prevent the result from being subject to globbing and word splitting, though.

Comment: For clarity, bash expands `$bsl` and quotes the resulting string here, backslash removal on the pattern is performed later by the pattern matching mechanism. The following demonstrates the different expansion rules applied to pattern and replacement parts clearly: `var='\\a\b' bsl='\\'; echo "${var//$bsl/$bsl}"`. This bugged me for almost a year, damn.